# Query optimization on millions of records

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I try to optimize my query , for have a better time of response with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` 
WHERE MATCH (name,tags) 
AGAINST ('toto' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `id` DESC  LIMIT 8
```

Database structure

```
Navicat MySQL Data Transfer

Source Server         : host
Source Server Version : 50550
Source Host           : 137.74.231.89:3306
Source Database       : megaboss

Target Server Type    : MYSQL
Target Server Version : 50550
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 2016-09-28 20:43:25
```

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for videos
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `embed` tinytext,
  `description` text,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hd` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `categories` (`categories`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1273355 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With a records count

```
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0069
Controller Execution Time ( Engine / Search )   1.3354
Total Execution Time    1.3430
```

Without a records count

```
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0063
Controller Execution Time ( Engine / Search )   0.0147
Total Execution Time    0.0216
```

It's very slow when i count the number of results ( for my pagination system )

```
$query->get('videos')->num_rows();
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Why are you using FULLTEXT indexes for everything?

Comment: What's causing the most slow down? Is it the `WHERE` clause or the `ORDER BY`? If you remove those two clauses and still apply `LIMIT 8` then is it still slow?

Comment: I have not show the query wich selects all the records for a given query

Comment: Consider usage of [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html). Also, try to replace `$query->get('videos')->num_rows()` with `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM videos` or [count_all_results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

Comment: Can you do an explain on the query being ran by your query builder/ORM and provide us the output? Also, it might be faster to just do two separate queries (one for count, one for the results themselves) as was stated by @AlexanderPopov